# Enabling an Edit on Shapefile in QGIS only with a password?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, authentication

I´m customizing some tasks in QGIS 2.14 using Python.

I am managing these edits in different layers (always shapefile layers, not database).

In one of them I want the users to enter a password before they can edit.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Is it a hard request that noone can alter the file under all circumstances? In this case i don´t see a chance other than encrypting the file itself (in a vera-crypt container or a zip file) as a shape file does not allow it. A possible solution within Qgis itself might work with a plug-in that the users have to use where you implement the password protection via python. But if someone does not use your plugin it will still be normally editable.